# Bootbox disappears on Jquery event .click

Tags: jquery, html

When I click the `a` link I want to show my confirmation message but it disappears immediately. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#deleteButton').click(function () {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
            return result;
        });
    });
});
```

I use struts tag in the html code:

```
<s:a action="delete" id="deleteButton">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
$('#deleteButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
        if(result)
        {
           window.location = "YOUR URL";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: e.preventDefault() will prevent the page from redirecting. Then you can use your own code for redirecting to a page.

Comment: I just want the result is true if my action is successful, if remarries is no remains on the page! I do not have to do any kind of redirects.